# How to use template_any_ID() into Ui Layout?

Tags: python

I found this in the Blender API, and I'm curious to try it out:

```
template_any_ID(data, property, type_property, text='', text_ctxt='', translate=True)
```

I am intrigued by this Template, but I don't really understand what it is for and how it works.

Can anyone explain?

I was trying something like this:

```
mat = C.object.active_material
layout.template_any_ID(mat.preview, 'icon_id', 'id_type', text='', text_ctxt='', translate=True)
```

But I get error:

```
uiTemplateAnyID: pointer property not found: ImagePreview.icon_id
```

I also tried with the 'name' property but not even this function.

Another question I don't really understand, what is required to actually use in **type_property**?

What's going on here? What is missing? Where am I wrong?

The documentation is partially cofused for me, and I can't find any examples on google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Look at the code**

With any blender layout, try grepping the `bl_ui` code to see if it has been used

and will see this has been used in the scene properties panel.

*`bl_ui/properties_scene.py`*

```
class SCENE_PT_keying_set_paths(SceneButtonsPanel, SceneKeyingSetsPanel, Panel):
    bl_label = "Active Keying Set"
    bl_parent_id = "SCENE_PT_keying_sets"
    ...

    scene = context.scene
    ks = scene.keying_sets.active

    ...


    ksp = ks.paths.active
    if ksp:
        col = flow.column(align=True)
        col.alignment = 'RIGHT'

        col.template_any_ID(ksp, "id", "id_type", text="Target ID-Block")
```

[image]
*Target ID Block: where I've selected camera*

and will see that this is not unlike a driver variable target, in that it lets us set the `ID` type of object, before selecting an object of that `id_type`

```
>>> ks = C.scene.keying_sets.active
>>> ksp = ks.paths.active
>>> ksp.id
bpy.data.objects['Camera']

>>> ksp.id_type
'OBJECT'
```

or alternatively to the camera data part

```
>>> ksp.id
bpy.data.cameras['Camera']

>>> ksp.id_type
'CAMERA'
```

*ie* we are setting a pointer to object  `ksp.id` to "any type" based on the `id_type`.

Comment: Ah Ok, so I was completely off track. That's basically what that template is for

Comment: Yes I believe so. Leads to another question an can we set up our own  "anytype" pointer?  `PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.ID)`