# Making an AnyType Pointer

Tags: python

Further to this question on how to mark up an any type pointer, can we create one.

[How to use template_any_ID() into Ui Layout?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/214038/how-to-use-template-any-id-into-ui-layout)

```
import bpy

class Test(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    id : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.ID)
    id_data : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.ID)
    id_type : bpy.props.EnumProperty(
            items = [
                ('OBJECT', "Object", "Object type"),
                ('SCENE', "Scene", "Scene"),
                ],
            default = 'OBJECT'
            )
                
class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        scene = context.scene
        layout.template_any_ID(scene.foo, "id", "id_type", text="Foo")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Test)
    bpy.types.Scene.foo = bpy.props.PointerProperty(
            type=Test,
            )

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 3):

I arrived to this :

[image]

I couldn't make Simulation and PointCloud work since they're not really of [type ID](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ID.html) for some reason.

This is much uglier than you expected but I kind of made it work with this monstrosity. It doesn't follow python guidelines for naming attributes but I don't think anyone cares :) :

```
import bpy


class Test(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    Action : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Action)
    Armature : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Armature)
    Brush : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Brush)
    Camera : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Camera)
    CacheFile : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.CacheFile)
    Collection : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Collection)
    Curve : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Curve)
    VectorFont : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.VectorFont)
    GreasePencil : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.GreasePencil)
    Image : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Image)
    Key : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Key)
    Light : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Light)
    Library : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Library)
    FreestyleLineStyle : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.FreestyleLineStyle)
    Lattice : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Lattice)
    Mask : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Mask)
    Material : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Material)
    Mesh : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Mesh)
    MovieClip : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.MovieClip)
    NodeTree : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.NodeTree)
    Object : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Object)
    PaintCurve : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.PaintCurve)
    Palette : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Palette)
    ParticleSettings : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.ParticleSettings)
    LightProbe : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.LightProbe)
    Scene : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Scene)
    Sound : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Sound)
    Speaker : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Speaker)
    Text : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Text)
    Texture : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Texture)
    Volume : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Volume)
    WindowManager : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.WindowManager)
    World : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.World)
    WorkSpace : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.WorkSpace)
    id_type : bpy.props.EnumProperty(
            items = [
                ('Action', "Action", "", "ACTION", 1),
                ('Armature', "Armature", "", "ARMATURE_DATA", 2),
                ('Brush', "Brush", "", "BRUSH_DATA", 3),
                ('Camera', "Camera", "", "CAMERA_DATA", 4),
                ('CacheFile', "Armature", "", "FILE", 5),
                ('Collection', "Collection", "", "OUTLINER_COLLECTION", 6),
                ('Curve', "Curve", "", "OUTLINER_DATA_CURVE", 7),
                ('VectorFont', "Font", "", "FONT_DATA", 8),
                ('GreasePencil', "Grease Pencil", "", "GREASEPENCIL", 9),
                ('Image', "Image", "", "IMAGE_DATA", 10),
                ('Key', "Key", "", "SHAPEKEY_DATA", 11),
                ('Light', "Light", "", "LIGHT", 12),
                ('Library', "Library", "", "LIBRARY_DATA_DIRECT", 13),
                ('FreestyleLineStyle', "Line Style", "", "LINE_DATA", 14),
                ('Lattice', "Lattice", "", "LATTICE_DATA", 15),
                ('Mask', "Mask", "", "MOD_MASK", 16),
                ('Material', "Material", "", "MATERIAL", 17),
                ('Mesh', "Mesh", "", "MESH_DATA", 18),
                ('MovieClip', "Movie Clip", "", "TRACKER", 19),
                ('NodeTree', "Node Tree", "", "NODETREE", 20),
                ('Object', "Object", "", "OBJECT_DATA", 21),
                ('PaintCurve', "Paint Curve", "", "CURVE_BEZCURVE", 22),
                ('Palette', "Palette", "", "COLOR", 23),
                ('ParticleSettings', "Particle", "", "PARTICLES", 24),
                ('LightProbe', "Light Probe", "", "LIGHTPROBE_CUBEMAP", 25),
                ('Scene', "Scene", "", "SCENE_DATA", 26),
                ('Sound', "Sound", "", "SOUND", 28),
                ('Speaker', "Speaker", "", "SPEAKER", 29),
                ('Text', "Text", "", "TEXT", 30),
                ('Texture', "Texture", "", "TEXTURE", 31),
                ('Volume', "Volume", "", "VOLUME_DATA", 32),
                ('WindowManager', "Window Manager", "", "WINDOW", 33),
                ('World', "World", "", "WORLD", 34),
                ('WorkSpace', "Workspace", "", "WORKSPACE", 35),
                ],
            default = 'Object',
            name = "ID Type",
            )

    def draw(self, layout, context):
        split = layout.split(factor=0.1, align=True)
        split.prop(self, "id_type", text="", icon_only=True)
        split.prop(self, self.id_type, text="")

    @property
    def value(self):
        return getattr(self, self.id_type)


                
class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        scene = context.scene
        scene.foo.draw(layout, context)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Test)
    bpy.types.Scene.foo = bpy.props.PointerProperty(
            type=Test,
            )

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

And if you want to get the ID value from elsewhere in the code :

```
print(scene.foo.value)
```