# Making a generic "ID"/datablock pointer property in an add-on

Tags: python, interface, add-on, properties, linked-data

I'm making an add-on and would like to have properties for selecting ID-blocks and data paths, similar to those in `KeyingSetPath`. Here's how I'm declaring them:

```py
item: PointerProperty(name="Data",
                      type=bpy.types.ID,
                      description="Data with an animatable property")
item_type: EnumProperty(name="Data type", items=id_type_items, default="OBJECT")
data_path: StringProperty(name="Data path",
                          description="RNA path of property to check")
```

Here's how I'm making the UI (referencing `properties_scene.py`):

```py
flow = layout.grid_flow(row_major=False, columns=0, even_columns=False, even_rows=False, align=True)

layout.use_property_split = True
layout.use_property_decorate = False

col = flow.column()
col.template_any_ID(myobject, "item", "item_type", text="Target ID-Block")
col.separator()
col.template_path_builder(myobject, "data_path", myobject.item)
```

However, the resulting search box is always disabled/grayed-out. As far as I can tell the only difference between the property that I declared and `KeyingSetPath.id` is that mine is created dynamically (i.e., in a Python script). What else could I be doing wrong?

Strangely, if I change the property type to a *specific* `ID` subclass, like `Object`, it works. The documentation suggests this might be intentional, but I can't find the code that enforces it:

> **type** (*class*) – A subclass of `bpy.types.PropertyGroup` or `bpy.types.ID`.

If it is intentional, what is the reason for the limitation, and why is `KeyingSetPath.id` exempt?

**Update 1**: `KeyingSetPath.id` does have "editable" and "type" functions set, to dynamically determine those things, and I can't set those functions from Python, but it seems like it should still work correctly without them. I don't need the type of the data block so I tried just using `template_ID` instead of `template_any_ID`, but then the field disappears entirely!

**Update 2**: I found [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/246171/166618) which makes their own ID type selector and search box but does so by creating a separate property for every single ID data type. It would still be nice to know why template_any_ID doesn't work.

**Update 3**: I figured out that it is indeed the "type" function that makes it work for `KeyingSetPath.id`. `ui_but_add_search` calls `RNA_property_pointer_type` to get the pointed type, which calls `type_fn`, and then `search_id_collection` which looks for a collection that holds that type. I'll see if I can make a workaround or patch.

Comment: Hello ! Yes, I believe the difference is the AnyType pointer defined in keying set is coded in C and it's not possible to create such pointer in Python. I suspect under the hood it acts like the monstrosity I created in the answer you linked at the end of your question. Would need to parse the source code to be sure though.

Comment: `KeyingSetPath.id` is defined directly as a property in the C code, not a getter function. You can check this with `bpy.types.KeyingSetPath.bl_rna.properties['id']`. It's declared in `rna_animation.c` `rna_def_keyingset_path`, and the line `RNA_def_property_struct_type(prop, "ID");` seems to suggest that it's a pointer property with type `ID`, just like the one I defined.

Comment: Except you defined it using the python API, not in C code. Which is not supported

Comment: Yes. I'd like to know why it's not supported.

Comment: This is not really a question we can answer on this site though. The reason is the dev team either chose to or didn't have enough ressources to implement this feature. This is unfortunately not the right site for a feature request, you can try to use the official channel to ask this question https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UILayout.template_any_ID` calls `UILayout.prop` which for pointer properties calls `UILayout.prop_search`. That first first checks if it's provided the object and property name of a collection to search through, and if not, uses the appropriate main collection for the pointed type. There is no collection of `ID` though, so this fails for our case. But, we can shortcut `UILayout.template_any_ID` and `UILayout.prop` and call `UILayout.prop_search` directly, with our own search collection. With that, here's a version of `template_any_ID` that calls `UILayout.prop_search` directly (and also uses the property name instead of "ID-Block:" for the label):

````py
id_type_to_collection_name = {
    'ACTION': 'actions',
    'ARMATURE': 'armatures',
    ...
    'WORKSPACE': 'workspaces',
    'WORLD': 'worlds'
}

def template_any_ID(layout: bpy.types.UILayout, data: typing.Any, property: str, type_property: str, text: str='', text_ctxt: str='', translate: bool=True) -> None:
    split = layout.split(factor=0.33)

    # FIRST PART
    row = split.row()

    # Label - either use the provided text, or will become "ID-Block:"
    if text != '':
        row.label(text=text, text_ctxt=text_ctxt, translate=translate)
    elif data.bl_rna.properties[property].name != '':
        row.label(text=data.bl_rna.properties[property].name, text_ctxt=text_ctxt, translate=translate)
    else:
        row.label(text="ID-Block:")

    # SECOND PART
    row = split.row(align=True)

    # ID-Type Selector - just have a menu of icons

    # HACK: special group just for the enum,
    # otherwise we get ugly layout with text included too...
    sub = row.row(align=True)
    sub.alignment = 'LEFT'

    sub.prop(data, type_property, icon_only=True)

    # ID-Block Selector - just use pointer widget...

    # HACK: special group to counteract the effects of the previous enum,
    # which now pushes everything too far right.
    sub = row.row(align=True)
    sub.alignment = 'EXPAND'

    type_name = getattr(data, type_property)
    if type_name in id_type_to_collection_name:
        icon = data.bl_rna.properties[type_property].enum_items[type_name].icon
        sub.prop_search(data, property, bpy.data, id_type_to_collection_name[type_name], text='', icon=icon)
```
````

Comment: Hey it seems like a nice workaround ! Would you mind adding a snippet for how it should be used (called) in a script ?

Comment: It's just the same as `template_any_ID`, which I already used in my question. So instead of `col.template_any_ID(myobject, "item", "item_type")` it would be `template_any_ID(col, myobject, "item", "item_type")`.